# Подключение 74HC595N к ардуино

Tags: arduino

Есть такой проект, как Moppy, где проигрывается музыка на флоппи приводах. Также, покопавшись в коде я обнаружил возможность подключения drum инструментов посредством сдвигового регистра 74HC595N. В интернете я нашел только подключение по 3 проводам, но в коде прописано подключение по 5 проводам

```
#define DATA_PIN 2
#define SHIFT_CLOCK_PIN 3
#define LATCH_PIN 4
#define MASTER_CLEAR_PIN 5
#define OUTPUT_ENABLE_PIN 6
```

По этому поводу в глобальной сети ничего обнаружить так и удалось, а при подключении по 3 проводам ничего не работает. Я "перетыкал" уже всё что возможно, но ничего не выходит. Если нужно ещё что-то - спрашивайте.

Comment: Всегда подключал по трём. Остальные два очищают регистр и выключают выход. А собственно в чём вопрос?

Comment: Если два оставшихся не используете, то вы их подтянули куда-нибудь или они у вас просто в воздухе болтаются?

Comment: @nightflash, вопрос в том, что при таком подключении ничего не работает. Два оставшихся я подтянул на землю и питание как в схемах показано

Comment: Проверяйте всё. Берите логический анализатор и проверяйте сигналы. На трёхпроводной схеме всё прекрасно должно работать. Ну а если не работает, то подключите остальные два провода. Даташит на чип есть в интернете.